# Tools for functional testing a Java EE application with message-driven beans and web services

Tags: java, testing, jms, jax-ws, message-driven-bean

I need to **test a complete system** that talks to the world entirely by JMS and JAX-WS. The flow, more or less, is this:

1. Triggered by a single JMS message,
2. Queries a few other external systems (via JMS or webservice).
3. Listens for the answers on queues (sometimes for 1 request there are many replies expected).
4. Processes what's needed and sends replies back (via JMS) to the calling system (also one or more replies per one triggering message).

**I've been searching for a tool that could:**

- mock the external systems (that is, listen on other ends of queues, analyze requests and reply based on the contents of the request),
- connect to different message brokers, Active MQ and Websphere MQ being the most wanted,
- create test case logic,
- compare the results with the expected behaviour.

The only thing that comes close so far is jMeter; it lacks only the ability to listen on a queue. **Any other ideas?** Could be free or commercial.

In the end, it seems to me I'd have to deploy a series of message-driven beans as mocks, but I want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: *functional testing* is a synonym for *acceptance testing* which is verifying that a product meets the customers requirements. Usually a paper (excel) centric test with little test automation...

Comment: @Andreas_D Yeah, I had trouble naming that. It's not integration-testing, as only one system will be checked in isolation. Maybe I should call it "system testing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resorted to writing my own set of MDBs.

Cons:

- much repetitive work,
- not reusable (a dedicated solution to the project),
- missed the possibility to learn a tool that could make my life easier next time,

Pros:

- full control of the test flow,
- ability to deploy it in the target environment (WAS 7) — probably out of the question with SoapUI,
- wrote it in a way that allows developing large test sets in a fast and efficient way.

Some colleagues I asked also recommended this approach. I'm a disappointed I haven't found a better way.

Answer (score 1):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) has native support for testing web services and JMS. If you doesn't like it then build a small test framework using Spring (spring-ws) and activeMQ.

Comment: +1 for SoapUI - I forgot to state in the question that I'm already evaluating it. Thanks anyway.